# How to apply CSS for border color in Bootstrap Select2 Dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using boostrap4.
I am trying to apply below css to the html elements.

```
.req 
{
   border-left: 2px solid #FF6600;
}
```

it is working fine with input elements but not worked with Select2 dropdown element.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Select2 Bootstrap Theme**

[image]

For Select2 drop down theme,

Apply the css to the span like this,

```
<span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single form-control input-lg" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-e8ez-container" style="
border: 2px solid #FF6600;">
```

**Drop Downs**

For just Drop downs, you will need to give the css class to button, see an example below,

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle req" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
          </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

**CSS**

Your css lass needs to have `!important` in it.

```
.req 
{
  border-left: 2px solid #FF6600 !important;  
}
```

**Example**

https://codepen.io/anjanasilva/pen/WaMxBR

Hope this helps.

Comment: @anand I have updated my answer. Would you like to have a look?